# Could not connect to the database Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: java, sql-server

I am running a SQL Server Express 10.50.4000.0 on my machine.
I have enabled on the TCP/IP and made sure the port is set to 1433.
I have added an exception in my firewall for 1433. 
The server service is running.
I have tried localhost and the computer name and both give the same error.
When i try localhost\SQLEXPRESS or [USER-PC]\SQLEXPRESS I received an error saying it could not find the database.

```
String driverName = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
Class.forName(driverName);

String serverName = "localhost";
String instanceName = "ALLEN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS";
String serverPort = "1433";
String database  = serverName +":" + serverPort+"/"+instanceName;
String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + database;
String username = "sa";
String password = "password";

connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

I receive the error:

```
Could not connect to the database Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect
```

with no additional context to investigate.

Comment: What is the name of the database?  I think it may need to be included in the connection string: `jdbc:jtds:<server_type>://<server>[:<port>][/<database>]`

Comment: Have you tried making a connection to that port with `telnet`?

Comment: telnet can not appear to establish a connection.

Comment: Is the SQL Server client (or application) and the instance on your local machine?  IF so, the firewall shouldnt be an issue; otherwise, if you cannot telnet from the client to the SQL instance, you have a firewall problem.

Comment: I also agree with Kevin. It looks like you havent specified the database catalog.  The SQL Server instance name is likely to be [User-PC]\SQLEXPRESS, as this is the default for express.  You then need to tell it what database you want to connect to.

Comment: I changed    String instanceName = "ALLEN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS";String database = serverName +":" + serverPort+"/"+instanceName; this does not change the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your connection string needs to be in this format.  Found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.110).aspx

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<yourDBServerIPAddress>\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=AdventureWorks;user=sa;password=*****;
```

Answer (score 14):

1. Make Sure that your SQL Server Browser service is active.
2. Goto AllProgram->SQL Server  ->configuraton tools->SQL Server Configuration Manager->SQL Server Network Configuration-> Select your server instance and right click on TCP/IP then goto IPAddresses. Change/Place port number for all IP's as 1433. Also make sure that the IP Address is Active and Enabled. Save it and restart the server.

Comment: Adding one more important step for above answer.
After "Change/Place port number for all IP's as 1433", if the "TCP/IP" is disabled by default then, enable it manually. Then, restart Sql server instance and start using.

Happy Coding.. Cheers

Answer (score 6):

There is no database server listening on localhost:1433

Check that the SQL Server Browser Service is running

So maybe using the ip address instead of localhost helps.

Comment: SQL Server Browser is currently running, and replacing the localhost with the ip did not appear to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Configuration Manager:
Start -> Microsoft SQL Server -> Configuration Tools -> SQL Server Configuration Manager
Enable the TCP/IP: from the left hand tree choose:
SQL Server Network Configuration-> Protocol for SQLEXPRESS-> TCP/IP
Right click and enable it.
Double click the TCP/IP and click on the “IP Addresses” Tab
Adding TCP/IP port : Enter TCP Port value to 1433 then click apply
Restart SQL Server: from the left hand tree, choose:
SQL Server Services -> SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) -> right click and restart.

Comment: Hi Sidharthan, proper formatting would greatly improve the readability and thus usefulness of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:
Instead of using jtds driver use **mssql-jdbc-9.4.0.jre8.jar**

Replace:

```
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<IP>:port/<DatabaseName>",userid,password);
```

With:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<IP>:port/<DatabaseName>",userid,password);
```

Solution 2:

Add **ssl=request** parameter in the connection string

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<IP>:port/<DatabaseName>;ssl=request",userid,password);
```